# Most efficient way to validate multiple textboxes against a tolerance value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

I have a series of text boxes in a table to gather input as below:

[image]

The user will input a target and actual value for each measurement point they require. I would then like to validate the actual values against the target values based upon the tolerance inputted in the tolerance textbox. The tolerance will be the same for all measurement points inputted, however the user will not always input all 10 measurement points.

I have also created a very basic class containing a function that accepts the target, actual and tolerance values then returns a Boolean depending on whether the actual value is within tolerance. I realise I could use this with a ruck load of if statements to check each textbox for input then use the class to perform the validation, however this seems like a lot of code repetition and a bit crude. My question being is there a better way I can perform this validation?

**EDIT** Class content

```
Public Class TolerenceHelper

Public Function IsInTolerence(ByVal target As Integer, ByVal actual As Integer, ByVal tolerence As Integer) As Boolean

Dim upper As Integer = target + tolerence
    Dim lower As Integer = target - tolerence

    If actual < lower OrElse actual > upper Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

Calling the function as below:

```
Dim m1 As TolerenceHelper
    Dim flag As Boolean = True

    m1 = New TolerenceHelper

    If m1.IsInTolerence(Integer.Parse(txtT1.Text), Integer.Parse(txtA1.Text), Integer.Parse(txtTolerance.Text)) = False Then
        flag = False
    End If

    If flag = False Then
        lblTest.Text = "Out of tolerance"
    Else
        lblTest.Text = "In tolerance"
    End If
```

Comment: _"I have also created a very basic class"_ Then show us this class. How could we improve something that we don't see. Apart from that, code-improvement belongs to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Apologies Tim, added class content. I wasn't aware of the site you linked to so I'll post my question there. Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your helper method seems to be ok, but you haven't shown the important part that you want to improve. The part where you load all textboxes and check whether they are valid or not.

Here is an approach that uses a custom class `Measurement`. You can use

```
Math.Abs(target.Value - actual.Value) <= tolerance
```

to determine if the value is valid according to the target and the tolerance.

```
Public Class Measurement
    Public Property Tolerance As Int32
    Public Property Target As Int32
    Public Property Value As Int32

    Public ReadOnly Property IsValid As Boolean
        Get
            Return Math.Abs(Target - Value) <= Tolerance
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

I would add all textboxes into the same container control like a `Panel`. Then you could use `Enumerable.OfType` to find the relevant textboxes. I use `Enumerable.Zip` to bring the values and the  targets together. Use `Int32.TryParse` to validate the text.

```
Dim tolerance As Int32
If Not Int32.TryParse(txtTolerance.Text, tolerance) Then
    lblTest.Text = "Enter a valid tolerance! Tolerance must be a positive integer(incl. zero)."
    Return
End If

Dim value As Int32
Dim allTxtTarget = From txt In Me.PnlMeasurement.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                   Where txt.ID Like "txtT#*" AndAlso Int32.TryParse(txt.Text, value)
                   Let x = New With {.TextBox = txt, .Value = value, .Type = "Target", .Number = txt.ID.Substring(4)}
                   Order By x.Number
                   Select x
Dim allTxtActual = From txt In Me.PnlMeasurement.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                   Where txt.ID Like "txtA#*" AndAlso Int32.TryParse(txt.Text, value)
                   Let x = New With {.TextBox = txt, .Value = value, .Type = "Value", .Number = txt.ID.Substring(4)}
                   Order By x.Number
                   Select x
Dim allMeasurements = allTxtTarget.Zip(allTxtActual,
    Function(target, actual) New Measurement With {
        .Tolerance = tolerance,
        .Target = target.Value,
        .Value = actual.Value
    }).ToList()
```

Output the results:

```
For i As Int32 = 0 To allMeasurements.Count - 1
    Dim m = allMeasurements(i)
    Console.WriteLine("Measurement {0}: Tolerance:{1} Target:{2} Value:{3} Valid:{4}",
                      i+1, tolerance, m.Target, m.Value, m.IsValid)
Next
```

If you actually need to check if all or at least one measurement is valid you can use:

```
Dim allValid = allMeasurements.All(Function(m) m.IsValid)
Dim anyValid = allMeasurements.Any(Function(m) m.IsValid)
```

or to find the highest valid measurement:

```
Dim validMeasurements = From m In allMeasurements 
                        Where m.IsValid
                        Order By m.Value Descending
Dim highestMeasurement = validMeasurements.FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation Tim. This seems like a much better way of doing things. Just had to change the Where clause from `txt.Name` to `txt.ID`.

Comment: @Jimsan: I've overlooked the ASP.NET tag. Edited my answer.